# How to use Excel VBA to extract Memo field from Access Database?

Tags: excel, ms-access, memo

I have an Excel spreadsheet.  I am connecting to an Access database via ODBC.  Something along then lines of:

```
Set dbEng = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.40")
Set oWspc = dbEng.CreateWorkspace("ODBCWspc", "", "", dbUseODBC)
Set oConn = oWspc.OpenConnection("Connection", , True, "ODBC;DSN=CLIENTDB;")
```

Then I use a query and fetch a result set to get some table data.

```
Set oQuery = oConn.CreateQueryDef("tmpQuery")
oQuery.Sql = "SELECT idField, memoField FROM myTable"
Set oRs = oQuery.OpenRecordset
```

The problem now arises.  My field is a dbMemo because the maximum content length is up to a few hundred chars.  It's not that long, and in fact the value I'm reading is only a dozen characters.  But Excel just doesn't seem able to handle the Memo field content at all.  My code...

```
ActiveCell = oRs.Fields("memoField")
```

...gives error Run-time error '3146': ODBC--call failed.

Any suggestions?  Can Excel VBA actually get at memo field data?  Or is it just completely impossible.  I get exactly the same error from GetChunk as well.

```
ActiveCell = oRs.Fields("memoField").GetChunk(0, 2)
```

...also gives error Run-time error '3146': ODBC--call failed.

Converting to a text field makes everything work fine.  However some data is truncated to 255 characters of course, which means that isn't a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

- Try `Range.CopyFromRecordset` to see if it works.
- Try using `CStr(oRs.Fields("memoField"))` and assign to `Value2` of the `Range`/`ActiveCell`.
- Try making the memo field the last physical column in table. A memo field is read only when retrieved. There was/may-still-be an issue with memo fields that are not at physically at the end of a table.

All I can think of right now.

Comment: I tried CStr early on, thinking it was a problem with conversion, but that raised exactly the same error.  I'll try the other two options, thanks.